The constant in Gronwall's inequality
The classical Gronwall's inequality is as follows:
Assume that
$$
f(t)\leq K+\int_0^tf(s)g(s)ds,
$$
where $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are continuous functions in $[0,T],$ $g(t)\geq 0$ for $t\in [0,T],$ and $K\geq 0.$ Then
$$
f(t)\leq Ke^{\int_0^tg(s)ds}
$$
Proof. Denote $U(t)=K+\int_0^tf(s)g(s)ds,$ then $$U^{'}(t)=f(t)g(t)\leq U(t)g(t)$$ since $g(t)\geq 0.$
Hence we have
$$
U(t)\leq U(0)e^{\int_0^tg(s)ds}=Ke^{\int_0^tg(s)ds},
$$
Then
$$
f(t)\leq U(t)\leq Ke^{\int_0^tg(s)ds}.
$$
I didn't find the role of the non-negativity of $K$. I think the condition of $K\geq 0$ is unnecessary. Am I right?

Seems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%2527s_inequality Agrees with you.

In the book of W.Walter: Ordinary Differential Equations, p.317 this version is stated  as "Generalized Lemma of Gronwall".
